# Java - JTree not following Path hierarchy

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need to create a tree node that uses a HashMap to build a tree of files, the key of the HashMap is the Path and it's Value is the File Name. I've implemented a code that breaks down the key value to build the hierarchy:

```
public void createNode(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("SQL Scripts");
        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree.setModel(treeModel);
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            String value = map.get(key);
            String[] path = key.split("/");
            DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = root;
            for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                boolean found = false;
                int index = 0;
                Enumeration e = parent.children();
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
                    if (node.toString().equals(path[i])) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                if (!found) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(path[i]);
                    treeModel.insertNodeInto(child, parent, index);
                    parent = child;
                } else {
                    parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) treeModel.getChild(parent, index);
                }
            }
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(value);
            treeModel.insertNodeInto(child, parent, parent.getChildCount());
        }
    }
```

But for some reason that I can't indentify, it is not working. I still get the following result:

[image: Result from createNode methode]

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong on my code implementation?

Comment: `String[] path = key.split("/");` - but your path strings don't seem to contain `/`, try using `String[] path = key.split(File.separator);` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I gave it a try but when I ran it I got an execption: ```java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException```

Comment: Don't you love windows, try using `key.replace(File.separatorChar, '/').split("/")` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer Windows is great! haha but yes ```key.replace(File.separatorChar, '/').split("/")``` solved my problem! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to split a Windows file path using `/`, except, Windows file paths are separated by `\`, which of course is also an escape character of regular expressions

## You could...

Use `key.replace(File.separatorChar, '/').split("/")` to change the `\` to `/` and the split on it

## Or...

```
File file = new File(key);
Path path = file.toPath();
// Path path = Paths.get(key);
for (int index = 0; index < path.getNameCount(); index++) {
    String subPath = path.getName(index));
    //...
}
```

## Or...

```
File file = new File(key);
Path path = file.toPath();
// Path path = Paths.get(key);
Iterator<Path> it = path.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Path next = it.next();
    String subPath = path.getFileName();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Using ```key.replace(File.separatorChar, '/').split("/")``` actually already solved the problem. Thanks for the suggestions! Tbh first really helpful reply I've got here on the site 

Comment: I kind of like the `Path` workflow, as it removes the "assumptions" about file paths and makes Java to all the work ... although the naming convention leaves a little to be desired (`path.getNameCount` ... not really obvious ... to an idiot like that is )

Comment: The Path workflow there is quite good. Might end up implementing it. And indeed about the naming convention haha ... Java leaves some things to be desired 